# How can i parallelize on multiple cores a parent-child recursive generation on python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, parent-child

I've a parent-child graph like this:

```
graph2 = {'Node': [0, 0, 0],
'children': [{'Node': [0, 0, 0], 'children': []},
{'Node': [1, 0, 0], 'children': []},
{'Node': [0, 1, 0], 'children': []},
{'Node': [0, 0, 1], 'children': []}]}
```

I've a function that returns a list of the leaf nodes of the graph, a function that generate children from a single leaf node (parent) and a function that say `Parent['children'] : output of child_generator` (that is a list of nodes with no children like `[{'Node': [0, 0, 1], 'children': []}, {'Node': [0, 1, 0], 'children': []}]`).

My task is to populate this graph with children in a recursive way but in a parallelize logic on multiple cores:

I tried this:

```
graph2 = {'Node': [0, 0, 0],
'children': [{'Node': [0, 0, 0], 'children': []},
{'Node': [1, 0, 0], 'children': []},
{'Node': [0, 1, 0], 'children': []},
{'Node': [0, 0, 1], 'children': []}]}
k = 1
for k in range(1,20):

    for result,leave in zip((Parallel(n_jobs=12)(delayed(child_generator_4)(4,k,[0.4,0.1,0.1,0.4], float(0.43), i) for i in get_leaves([graph2],k))), get_leaves([graph2],k)):
        leave['children'] = result
# took 1m e 10s to be runned
```

Forgot about child_generator parameters (k is the iterator and correspond to the k-th generation, besides the level where we can find leaf nodes, and i is the single leaf node)

Can you please write a code that do this in a full parallel way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you cannot do that *efficiently* in parallel. This seems surprising and frustrating, but this is the actual current state of parallelism in CPython... Multithreading cannot make this code faster because of the insane Global Interpreter Lock. Multiprocessing can hardly make this faster because of the expensive inter-process communication (pickling) which make this very slow (actually possibly slower than in sequential). It only worth it if your computation is very intensive on small Python objects. This is not the case for a graph represented with dictionary like in your code.

Using another representation based on Numpy array can help to actually be able to parallelise the code but it will still be a bit tricky and probably not scale (eg. since the size of Numpy arrays is immutable).

Python is clearly not a good language to implement parallel computation of dynamic graphs (it is only good to call C functions doing that efficiently). Please consider using another language (I doubt any module can do exactly what you want *efficiently and in parallel*). Low-level languages like C/C++ are pretty efficient for this. Language with a garbage collector like Java and C# will certainly not scale very well (or will introduce a significant overhead) because of the GC. Using a more efficient graph representation should help whatever the target language (maybe adjacency list based on optimized growing arrays possibly combined with efficient hash-maps).